# Execute an NSTimer in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I need to run an NSTimer in an app even after the user minimizes the app. The Timer is used to hit a web service every 15 seconds and after 4 minutes I need to perform certain navigations. How can this be done?

I know this question has been asked earlier too but I have not been able to find an appropriate answer.

Comment: As far as i know this is not possible, iOS is strict with the amount of work you can do while an app is not in the foreground. You might have up to a few minutes to do stuff in the background, but after a while iOS will stop your app. Their are exceptions for voip and some other things though

Comment: 4 minutes shouldn't be an issue right? I have heard Apple give you 10 minutes before the OS kills your app

Comment: i dont know if you can rely on it, but further reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: iOS kills the app after 30 seconds unless you request more time. And even then it's only 3 minutes. See beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.

Comment: @Tapani I'm not too sure if the app is killed as early as 30 seconds after moving into the background.

Comment: It probably depends on how many other apps are running in the device. If iOS decides that there are too many processes running and that would take too much battery then it kills your app. And if Apple's docs say that it's 30 seconds then you can't assume it's always more than 30 seconds. In the next iOS version it may be 30 seconds always and the your app does not work at all.

Answer (score 3):

You need a reason for it to be possible. 
If it's for navigation app, VOIP, or just for background downloads (in some cases), it's possible.
But otherwise, you can't do it.

Comment: So the scenario I presented is not possible at all?

Comment: You should make no assumption that you can execute in the background, unless you conform to one of the scenarios in which Apple guarantees execution time.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: You can't run NSTimer in background. Sorry. but this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Before you proceed, think about *why* it isn't easy to make a timer run when the app is in the background. It's because it empties the phone's battery. You get unhappy customers if you do that. Which Apple doesn't care much about, but Apple gets unhappy customers, which they care about a lot. Under Settings -> Battery Apple will tell the user which app used how much energy in the last 24 hours / 6 days, so people can find your app if it does waste energy in the background and throw it out.

Comment: Completely makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can configure you app to run in the background, but you have no control over how frequently iOS calls you app in the background.

I know this is a really bad solution and misuse of the service, but you could initiate a background file download and make your server to send data so slowly that it takes about 4 minutes. iOS will report to your app when the transfer is complete. If your app is not terminated iOS also reports the download progress to your app. But you can't open the app ui when the transfer is complete if the app is not in the foreground.

> 1. Create the configuration object using the
>      backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier: method of
>      NSURLSessionConfiguration.
> 2. Set the value of the configuration object’s
>      sessionSendsLaunchEvents property to YES.
> 3. if your app starts transfers
>      while it is in the foreground, it is recommend that you also set the
>      discretionary property of the configuration object to YES.
> 4. Configure
>      any other properties of the configuration object as appropriate.
> 5. Use
>      the configuration object to create your NSURLSession object.
>
> When all of the tasks associated with a background session are
>   complete, the system relaunches a terminated app (assuming that the
>   sessionSendsLaunchEvents property was set to YES and that the user did
>   not force quit the app) and calls the app delegate’s
>   application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:
>   method.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: The exact purpose I wish to fulfill here is to check a particular status by talking with the server over a web service and update the UI according to the server response. This happens for 4 minutes and then the user is shown a particaluar set of UI elements. I am pretty sure this won't qualify in background downloads.

Comment: I have implemented push notifications to get it done but I, for some reason, did not want to completely rely on push notifications because if they don't get delivered, it won't be a very good experience for the user.

Comment: You should send a remote notification from the server. That's the only way to open the ui when the app is in the background. And even with a notification the user has to manually click the notification to launch the app.

Comment: You could schedule a local notification after 4 minutes.

Comment: Just thinking out loud.. What if I schedule a silent local notification every 15 seconds?

Comment: That probably works. You can set "repeatInterval" in the notification.

Comment: I would be interested to know if ios somehow limits the frequency. Please share your experiences here.

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate.h  // using local notification to get some function call

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
 [self getNotificationPermission];
return YES;
}
```

This method used for permission

```
-(void)getNotificationPermission{

// Accept Action

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
acceptAction.identifier = @"Accept";
acceptAction.title = @"Yes i am OK";
acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
acceptAction.destructive = NO;
acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

// Reject Action

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *rejectAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
rejectAction.identifier = @"Reject";
rejectAction.title = @"On i am Not OK";
rejectAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;
rejectAction.destructive = YES;
rejectAction.authenticationRequired = YES;

// Reply Action

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *replyAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
replyAction.identifier = @"Reply";
replyAction.title = @"Reply";
replyAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
replyAction.destructive = NO;
replyAction.authenticationRequired = YES;

// Email Category

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *emailCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
emailCategory.identifier = @"Email";
[emailCategory setActions:@[acceptAction,rejectAction,replyAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[emailCategory setActions:@[acceptAction,rejectAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];

// Download Action

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *downloadAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
downloadAction.identifier = @"Download";
downloadAction.title = @"Download";
downloadAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
downloadAction.destructive = NO;
downloadAction.authenticationRequired = YES;

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *cancelAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
cancelAction.identifier = @"Cancel";
cancelAction.title = @"Cancel";
cancelAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground;
cancelAction.destructive = YES;
cancelAction.authenticationRequired = YES;


// Image Category

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *imageCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
imageCategory.identifier = @"Image";
[imageCategory setActions:@[downloadAction,cancelAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[imageCategory setActions:@[downloadAction,cancelAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];


NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:emailCategory,imageCategory, nil];
UIUserNotificationType notificarionType = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

// Register notification types and categories
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificarionType categories:categories];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

// This line of code is required for remote push notification
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings{

//UIUserNotificationType notificationtype = [notificationSettings types];

}

// You can check the current user notifiartions settings whenever you need it
 -(void)getReadyForNotification{

//UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
//[self checkSettings:settings];
}

// When appliation is in foregrounf this methid will get caled if you have scheduled a local notification
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

//CLRegion *region = notification.region;
if ([notification.category isEqualToString:@"Image"]) {
    NSLog(@"Image category notification is presented to the user");
}else if([notification.category isEqualToString:@"Email"]){
    NSLog(@"Email category notification is presented to the user");
}
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{

if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Accept"]) {
    [self printAlert:@"Accept"];
}else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Reject"]) {
    [self printAlert:@"Reject"];
}else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Reply"]) {
    [self printAlert:@"Reply"];
}else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Download"]) {
    [self printAlert:@"Download"];
}else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
    [self printAlert:@"Cancel"];
}
completionHandler();
}

-(void)printAlert:(NSString *)title
{
NSLog(@"%@ button is selected",title);
if ([title isEqualToString:@"Accept"])
{
}
else if ([title isEqualToString:@"Reject"])
{
}


}

// Callback for remote notification
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{
NSLog(@"handleActionWithIdentifier forRemoteNotification");
}
```

Set Local Notification on ViewController

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
localNotification.alertBody = @"How you are Feeling Today ?";
localNotification.category = @"Email";  // This should match categories identifier which we have defined in App delegate
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Using this code you will Get local notification after every cycle of time period if user select notification in foreground then open app in particular stage or screen you want. this code is also not breaching apple guidelines.

Comment: Right. You might want to remove the alert body though.. Bugging the user every 15 seconds (atleast in my case) would never be good